# Adding a smaller array to a larger array at a specified location (using variables)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

Suppose I have a 6x6 matrix I want to add into a 9v9 matrix, but I also want to add it at a specified location and not necessarily in a 6x6 block.

The below code summarizes what I want to accomplish, the only difference is that I want to use variables instead of the rows 0:6 and 3:9.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((9,9)) 
b = np.ones((6,6))

a[0:6,3:9] += b  #Inserts the 6x6 ones matrix into the top right corner of the 9x9 zeros
```

Now using variables:

```
rows = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
cols = np.array([3,4,5,6,7,8])

a[rows,3:9] += b #This works fine
a[0:6,cols] += b #This also works fine
a[rows,cols += b #But this gives me the following error: ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (6,6) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (6,)
```

I have spent hours reading through forums and trying different solutions but nothing has ever worked. The reason I need to use variables is because these are input by the user and could be any combination of rows and columns. This notation worked perfectly in MatLab, where I could add b into a with any combination of rows and columns.

Comment: `a[rows[:,None], cols] += b`, to index the rows with *rows*. 1-D arrays are different from matrices in MatLab.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

```
rows = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
cols = np.array([3,4,5,6,7,8])

a[rows,cols] += b
```

You could translate the last line to the following code:

```
for x, y, z in zip(rows, cols, b):
  a[x, y] = z
```

That means: `rows` contains the x-coordinate, `cols` the y-coordinate of the field you want to manipulate. Both arrays contain 6 values, so you effectively manipulate 6 values, and `b` must thus also contain exactly 6 values. But your `b` contains 6x6 values. Therefore this is a "*shape mismatch*". [This site](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) should contain all you need about indexing of `np.array`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I couldn't get the above solution to work. I read through the link and was able to get what I wanted with the np.ix_() function

Comment: Normally, @Michael Szczensny's answer should work for you: `a[rows[:,None], cols] += b`. At least, it does on your example.